# How can you safely use Perforce $Revision$ in LaTeX document?

Tags: latex, perforce

I'd like to include Perforce's `$Revision$` keyword in my LaTeX document.  However, the presence of `#` seems to mess thing up.  For example, if you have something like this:

> \cfoot{$Revision: #8 $}

you end up with an error like "Illegal parameter number in definition of \temp@a".  I did some searching and found packages (such as the LaTeX rcs package) that handle other keywords (such as Date) but nothing that appeared to handle the `#`.

Comment: Dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939547/hash-character-in-latex

Comment: I don't think so -- you can't control Perforce's behavior to get it to put in \# instead of # (AFAIK).

Comment: I agree this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\let \savecfoot \cfoot
\def \cfoot{\catcode`\#=12 \cfoothelp}
\def \cfoothelp #1{\savecfoot{#1}\catcode`\#=6 }
```

*New:*

To turn off the meaning of $ too:

```
\let \savecfoot \cfoot
\def \cfoot{\catcode`\#=12 \catcode`\$=9 \cfoothelp}
\def \cfoothelp #1{\savecfoot{#1}\catcode`\#=6 \catcode`\$=3 }
```

Comment: Cool, that seems to work.  BTW, is there an easy way to also turn off the special meaning of $ at the same time?

Comment: Yes. What do you want to do with the meaning of $?

Comment: I was thinking of just having them disappear.